# No wlan0 found with a Broadcom 4313

Tags: 11.10, wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Broadcom BCM 43XX Wireless card working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-get-broadcom-bcm-43xx-wireless-card-working)

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 on an Asus 1015PN netbook with 2 gigabytes memory using WUBI.

Got a Broadcom 4313 chipset (14e4:4727).

I wanted to connect my netbook to my mobile using *Joikuspot premium* and I was able to scan and find the wireless AP but wasn't able to obtain an IP so I set a static IP and disabled *ipv6* without any luck.

Then after reading a post I installed the broadcom wireless source, common and the firmware *(brcmwl-kernel-source)* using synaptic. After uninstalling the previous *brcm sta* driver which was downloaded form [here](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php).

After rebooting the system I did a `iwconfig` and was not able to find the *wlan0* interface which was there before, so I removed the drivers that I installed and reinstalled the old *broadcom sta* from their site, however I am still not able to find the interface but Ubuntu recognizes my WLAN card when I do a *lspci*.

How do I get *wlan0* back?

Answer (score 3):

You must delete all drivers for this Broadcom and then:

```
apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
echo blacklist acer_wmi >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Comment: Thank you, I found that there were two drivers which were conflicting with each other, so i removed all the _broadcom_ drivers, reinstalled and blacklisted a few drivers with the instructions given [here](http://wiki.debian.org/wl). But its back to the same situation once i restart, how do i make this permanent?